# Creating Item Receipts from POs via SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm in the process of creating a module to handle multi-PO consolidated shipments (fx imports) and writing a script to receive multiple POs with landed costs per line.

I'm using SuiteScript API 1.0

However, when I create the Item Receipt record (and include the PO# in the `createdfrom` field to create the link from IR to PO, during the process of copying the PO lines to the IR lines, I'm getting constant `SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION` errors.

The code in question is below:

```
            // ** set body fields
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('location',purchRec.getFieldValue('location'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('entity',purchRec.getFieldValue('entity'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('createdfrom',purchRec.getFieldValue('internalid'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('currency',purchRec.getFieldValue('currency'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('exchangerate',purchRec.getFieldValue('exchangerate'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('isbasecurrency',purchRec.getFieldValue('isbasecurrency'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('exchangerate',purchRec.getFieldValue('exchangerate'));
        receiptRec.setFieldValue('landedcostperline','T');

        log ('Receipt Record:'); log( receiptRec );
        // ** copy item lines
        var POlines = purchRec.getLineItemCount('item');
        for ( line=1 ; line<=POlines; line++) {
            var fulfill = purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','fulfillable',line); log('Fulfill?? '+fulfill)
            if (fulfill == 'T') {
                log('Fill From PO Line #'+line);
                receiptRec.selectNewLineItem('item');                                                                       log('Debug 1');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item',purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','item',line));            log('Debug 2');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','itemreceive','T',line);                                          log('Debug 3');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity',purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','quantity',line));    log('Debug 4');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate',purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','rate',line));            log('Debug 5');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','taxcode',purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','taxcode',line));      log('Debug 6');
                receiptRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','units',purchRec.getLineItemValue('item','units',line));          log('Debug 7');
                receiptRec.commitLineItem('item');                                                                          log('Debug 8');
            }
        }
```

The error is triggering at the `selectNewLineItem('item')` point.

`receiptRec` is the newly created `itemreceipt` record.
`purchRec` is the existing purchase order record.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot "create" a new Item Receipt record in Netsuite. You need to "transform" a Purchase Order into an Item Receipt using `nlapiTransformRecord('purchaseorder', purchaseorderid, 'itemreceipt')`. This will automatically copy all the line items, and then you can iterate through them to change quantities or remove lines completely, however you cannot add new lines.

See [this link](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3195956.html) in the documentation for more information.